# Using Proxies with NightmareJS

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I'm trying to have NightmareJS use some proxies.

This is how my code looks like:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');

var nightmare = Nightmare({
    switches: {
        'proxy-server': 'exampleProxy.io:19081',
        'ignore-certificate-errors': true
    },
    show: true
});

nightmare
    .goto('http://www.example.com')
```

The weird thing is: it sort of works, just incredibly slow, often with timeouts. I'm testing on a local machine. Without the proxy it's very fast. It can be seen as given that the proxy itself is fast.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: try `time curl -x http://exampleProxy.io:19081 http://www.example.com` to see how much time it takes to finish the request.

Comment: Yeah tried that, with CURL it's blazing fast... but need the functionality of Nightmare

Comment: If the page has ajax, that could be the very reason of the proxy serving slowly. Use the proxy on your chrome/firefox, and try to browse the page. If that fails, try with puppeteer. There is always a way.